# Iframe bloqueando propriedade do flash

Tags: html, html5, iframe, flash

Preciso adicionar um iframe do jogo TRANSFORMICE.

Parece fácil, correto? Sendo:

```
<iframe src="http://transformice.com" frameborder="0"  width="100%" height="100%" ></iframe>
```

Entretanto, há um pequeno erro(entretanto, considerável): Não aparece a "barrinha piscando".

Deveria estar assim: https://gyazo.com/1c6abc94b4989bc43bf8c5c0ae47be84

[NO IFRAME] Porém fica sem a barrinha: https://gyazo.com/b063b0592a73ad5eee8f3a219bbd7a04

Como posso corrigir?

Comment: Ainda usam flash?

Comment: Infelizmente...

Comment: Não da para ser um gif no lugar?

Comment: os navegadores deixaram de suporta flash por insegurança não foi ?

Comment: @ederwander por insegurança, performance, compatibilidade, usabilidade, indexação de motores de busca, etc...

Comment: Será que não é por o navegador não reconhecer a troca de foco pro frame? Se for você poderia tentar forçar esse foco com js.

Comment: Como faço isso?

Comment: Barrinha, você diz o cursor do campo de texto?

Comment: isso, exato!!!!